# Prove $\|Tx\|_\infty \le \|x\| $ for all $x$ belonging to a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**Here is the question:**
[image]

**And here is the given answer:**
[image]

---

I would like to ask in the first line of the proof, why $\|x^*_k\|$ is less or equal than $1$?
I guess zero belongs to $B(x^*_k,r)$ for any $k$, then $\|x^*_k - 0||<r<1$ but I don't know how to prove it. May I have some hints please?

Comment: $x_k^{*} \in B_E^{*}$ so $\|x_k^{*}\| \leq 1$. That is the definition of $B_E^{*}$.

Comment: $E^{*}$ is the set of all bounded linear maps from $E$ to $\mathbb K$. $B_E^{*}$ is the closed unit ball of $E^{*}$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy
Thank you. I thought that $B^*_E$ is the set of all bounded linear map from $B_E$ to $\mathbb K$ rather than $B(E^∗)$. The notations are confusing me.